# Difficulty implementing logarithmic barrier in Matlab.

Tags: convex-optimization, matlab, numerical-optimization, newton-raphson, gradient-descent

I'm trying to create a convex optimization code in Matlab , to deal with inequality constraints I'm using logarithmic barrier.Suppose we have inequality $g(x) =< 0$ to satisfy,so I define $\varphi  (x) = -log(-g(x))$,What if in an iteration $g(x)$ becomes positive? as $\varphi$ is not defined when $g(x) > 0$ ,the algorithm stuck in that $x$,I tried the code segment bellow but sometimes it cause the code to stuck in this" while" for ever:(beta is line search parameter)

```
while (g(x+ s*delta) > 0),
     s = BETA*s;
end % first get feasible point ... then search minimum
```

Do you have any idea how to deal with this?

Comment: If $g(x)\geq 0$ then there is definitely no way to exit that loop. So the point is that $g(x)$ itself must always be negative. Your code has to explicitly ensure that is the case _before_ you even get here. Unfortunately we don't have context here.

Comment: @MichaelGrant  So you mean defining logarithmic barrier is not enough to force $g(x)$ remain negative,and I have to take care of this before I even define logarithmic barrier am I right?If that's not the point can you give me some more hints?

Comment: That's correct. You still have to take explicit steps in your code to make sure that $g(x)$ stays positive.

Comment: @MichaelGrant Thank you so much for your hint.